# How to load one ad for screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, admob, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

This is my code:

```
AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.native_ad, null, true)
            val adView = view.findViewById<TemplateView>(R.id.medium_ad_template)
            
            adView.apply {
                AdLoader.Builder(context, context.getString(AR.string.native_unit_id))
                    .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                        setStyles(NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build())
                        setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                    }
                    .build()
                    .loadAd(request)
            }

            view
        }
    )
```

native_ad.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
        android:id="@+id/medium_ad_template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_medium_template_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The ad keeps refreshing on screen navigation

I tried to set a tag on the first load and keep check in it to see if the ad already loaded, but the view refreshed and the tag resets to the default value

Comment: Can you please specify the issue and also add some screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

In your case I think view is recreated because your flag value is reset while you change the screen to stop that try **rememberSaveable** as below.

> **rememberSaveable** which is similar to remember, but the stored value
> can survive process death or configuration changes.

```
val flag: MutableState<Boolean> = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = flag ){
       AndroidView(...)
  }
```

I hope It will work

Comment: 'rememberSaveable' save value on configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some flag that will remember that will allow to control for not reloading ad again . so have you checked with `rememberUpdatedState`

here is link of documentation for same

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#rememberupdatedstate

Answer (score 0):

By what I could understand about your question, Side effect is what you would be needing here. Put AndroidView method inside a Side effect block and define what you would like to update the block.

```
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = <On change of this your block is recomposed>){
       AndroidView(...)
  }
```

Note: If you don't want the block to update then just put a string in place of the key in launched effect.